# Is there any error in R code to get only prime numbers from 3 to 100?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, primes, break

I want to get prime number from 3 to 100, only using 'if', 'for', 'break', 'next'.
When I run the code, nothing shows up.
Is there any error in the code?

```
for (i in 3:100) {
  prime <- TRUE
  for (k in (2:i-1)) {
    if (i%%k == 0) {
      prime = FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  if (prime==TRUE) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

I want to get prime number (like 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...) only using 'if', 'for', 'break', 'next'.

Comment: You are missing parentheses: `for (k in (2:(i-1)))`

Answer (score 0):

@Roland in the comment has pointed out where the error is, i.e., `for (k in (2:(i-1)))`

---

Also, you can define a custom function `f` with a helper function `findPrimes`, e.g.,

```
f <- function(lb, ub) {
    findPrimes <- function(n) {
        if (n == 2) {
            return(n)
        }
        p <- Recall(n - 1)
        c(p, if (all(n %% p>0)) n)
    }
    v <- findPrimes(ub)
    v[v >= lb]
}
```

and

```
> f(3, 100)
 [1]  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```